# I cant extract instagram hashtags of a post with bs4

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, instagram

I wanted to extract hashtags from a specific post(given url) using BeautifoulSoup4. First I fetch the page using requests and I've tried find_all() to get every hashtag but it seems there is a hidden problem.

here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs



URL = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/CBz7-X6AOqK/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link'

r = requests.get(URL)
soup = bs(r.content,'html.parser')
items = soup.find_all('a',attrs={'class':' xil3i'})

print(items)
```

the result of this code is just an empty list. Can someone please help me with the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the page you are trying to scrape requires `javascript`. This means that some elements of the webpage are not there when you send a `GET` requests.

One way you can figure out if the webpage you are scraping requires `javascript` to populate the info you need is to simply save the html into a file:

```
URL = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/CBz7-X6AOqK/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link'

r = requests.get(URL)

with open('dump.html', 'w+') as file:
    file.write(r.text)
```

and then open that file into a web browser

If the file you open does not have the information you want to scrape then it is likely that it is automatically populated using `javascript`.

To get around this you can render the `javascript` using

- A web driver (like [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/)) that simulates a user going to those pages in a web browser
- [requests-HTML](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/), which is a slightly new package that allows you to render javascript on a page, and has so many other awesome features that are useful for web scraping

There is a larger group of people who work with selenium which makes debugging easier than with requests-HTML, but if you do not want to learn about a new module like selenium, requests-HTML is very similar to requests and picking it up should not be very difficult